# Resultant sum of an array when each element is XORed by any constant

Tags: algorithm, math, bit-manipulation, bitwise-xor

Given an array say nums = {1,2,3} and a constant C = 4 , The task is to find the sum of array elements where every element is first XORed by a constant C .

Result : (1⊕ 4) + (2 ⊕  4) + (3 ⊕ 4) = 18

When we have only one constant then it can be done easily but What if we have K such constants then how can we find the above result ?

Example : nums = {1,2,3}
Constants = 4 , 5 , 6
Then for each Constants(*queries*) , we need to evaluate the answer.

Comment: If can already do this for one "query", I fail to see what's keeping you from doing this for three queries.

Comment: You can evaluate the effect of each bit on the sum. Then the sum for a query can be computed by combining the results from individual bits. Of course, this is only useful if the number of queries is large compared to the number of bits in the numbers.

Comment: What is the maximum number of queries? Maximum value of C?

Comment: @babon  number of queries can go up to N (number of elements in array) , So the expected complexity will be O(n^2) which is costly , I need to reduce this complexity .

Comment: What do you mean by: Evaluate the answer? Do you want to have one answer as result or an array of anwwers (for each constant one)? Please explain what you expect as outcome for your example..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all input numbers and the constant C are less than 2^K (perhaps K=32 or K=64), for each `i` from 0 to K-1, count the number of input numbers that have a 1 in bit `i`. Call these counts `x[0], x[1], ..., x[K-1]` Suppose there are `N` input numbers.

Let `C` be a given constant. Let `x[i]'` be `x[i]` if the `i`'th bit of `C` is 0, otherwise `N-x[i]`.

Then the sum of the input numbers xored by C is `sum(2^i * x[i]', i=0..K-1)`.

This takes O(NK) time to prepare, and O(K) time for each query.

For example, if the input is `{1, 2, 3}`, then there's two numbers with bit 0 set (ie: 1 and 3), and two numbers with bit 1 set (ie: 2 and 3). Let K=3, so `x` is `{2, 2, 0}`.

If C=4, then `x'` is `{2, 2, 3-0} = {2, 2, 3}`. The sum is `2 + 2*2 + 4*3 = 18`.